# Publishing WebSite in VS Express Editions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, publish, visual-studio-express

I m trying to publish my website and dlls with vs2010 express edition. 
I tried aspnet_compiler -v /-p command. But it didnt work.!

So how can i publish my project for free ?

Comment: Assuming you're using the Web Developer express version, can't you just right-click on your web project (not the solution) and choose publish?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out... [PreCompile or Publish websites in Visual Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://swami-k.blogspot.com/2008/12/precompile-or-publish-websites-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why try publish in commandline, when you have a nice wizard which can do the same thing? It's a matter of few clicks.

For instance:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx